# Deutsche Werbungen für Akzent-Verbesserung

Tags: pronunciation

Ich möchte an meinem deutsches Akzent arbeiten. Ich möchte Werbungen auf Deutsch finden und danach versuchen, den/die SprecherIn einer Werbung zu imitieren. Zum Beispiel (auf Englisch):

- [LinkedIn Talent
  Pipepline](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=rE0PcZyTHEk#!)
- [Google Search Ads](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4uLwC5PAi7g)

Warum ich das machen möchte? Weil der/die SprecherIn einfach das beste Hochdeutsch spricht und es ganz kurz ist – also beste Bedingungen, um meinen Akzent zu verbessern.

Ich habe versucht, das zu finden, aber ich habe nichts gefunden. Kennt ihr solche Werbungen? Gibt es solche Werbungen in Deutschland oder ist das nur in der Amerika?

Comment: Seit wann wird in Werbespots Standarddeutsch gesprochen? Habe ich selten erlebt. Meist wird doch eher mit der Sprache gespielt. Schau lieber die Tageschau.

Comment: [Diese Frage über deutschsprachige Filme](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/404/what-movies-are-good-for-learners-who-want-to-improve-their-grammar-and-vocabula) könnte dann auch interessant für dich sein, wenn Filme als Alternative zu Werbung in Frage kommen.

Comment: Suche auf YouTube nach "Werbung" oder "Werbespot". Du bekommst Tausende davon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Den Ansatz, direkt bei Muttersprachlern „abzuschauen“, finde ich sehr gut. Werbespots haben zwar den Vorteil der Kürze, aber – wie schon in den anderen Antworten und Kommentaren angesprochen – wäre ich mir nicht sicher, was die „Sprachqualität“ (Hochdeutsch / Dialekt / Wortspiele / bewusste Fehler ([credits bernd_k](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2864/deutsche-werbungen-fur-akzent-verbesserung/2865#2865))) betrifft. Außerdem ist das Vokabular eher beschränkt.

Mein Tipp: Internet-Radio (Live-Streams) mit viel Sprachanteil (subjektiv-lokalpatriotisch gefärbte Auswahl):

- [Deutschlandfunk](http://www.dradio.de/dlf/)
- [Deutsche Welle](http://www.dw-world.de/dw/0,,265,00.html)
- [SWR 2](http://www.swr.de/swr2/)
- [Bayern 2](http://www.br-online.de/bayern2/)
- [SWR cont.ra](http://www.swr.de/contra/)
- [Bayern 5 aktuell](http://www.br-online.de/b5aktuell/)

Das hat den Vorteil, dass es gratis ist und dass die Sprecher Profis (gutes Deutsch) und die Themen aktuell sind.

Die Info-Kanäle (SWR cont.ra und B5 aktuell) wiederholen zudem die Nachrichten alle 15 oder 30 Minuten, so dass man denselben Text mehrmals hören kann. Bei der Deutschen Welle kann man die Inhalte online außerdem auch auf Englisch abrufen und so überprüfen, ob man alles richtig verstanden hat (oder worum es tatsächlich ging).

Answer (score 3):

Die Idee scheint mir ein wenig problematisch.

> Prominente z.B. vom Fußball sprechen kein reines Hochdeutsch, sondern
>   eine von ihrem Dialekt gefärbte Variante.
>
> Teilweise werden bewusst grammatikalische Fehler verwendet. Z.B.  [11
>   88 0](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKj-6yKSnLE)

Ich glaube nicht, dass es für einen nicht Muttersprachler einfach ist, zu entscheiden, welche Qualität ein Werbespot hat.

Ich würde eher raten deutsch synchronisierte Tonspuren auf DVDs zu verwenden.

Answer (score 3):

Hier ein paar Beispiele, die ich auf YouTube gefunden habe:

- [iPad-Werbespot (30 Sekunden)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQxjdj1nD8s)
- [Tiscali-Werbspot (90 Sekunden)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJ1AWtSSGV4)
- [Sky Deutschland Launch Spot (90 Sekunden)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cP4Uu2wo3I)
- ["Du bist Deutschland"-TV-Spot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKA1M4yaDmc)